# While updating a particular element in a nested list the entire list gets updated

Tags: python-3.x, list, nested-lists

I am trying to update a single element in my nested list structure

I wanted to initialize an empty list as below

```
a= [[0]*2]*2
a
[[0, 0], [0, 0]]
```

Now i want to update only the 0,0 th element. So i end up assigning that like below.

```
a[0][0] = 999
```

However i notice that the 0th element of each nested list is getting updated.

```
a
[[999, 0], [999, 0]]
```

So i have noticed that this does not happen if i Initialize the list as below

```
b = [[0,0],[0,0]]

b[0][0]=999

b
[[999, 0], [0, 0]]
```

Can anyone help in my understanding of the above two different approaches and why one works and the other does not.

Comment: Thank you. This was exactly what i wanted.